# Python Websocket Client - Multiple Subprocesses (45+)

Tags: python, websocket, subprocess

I have an interesting task ahead of me. I need to connect to 45 different websocket streams and stuff them all into the correct places. Sometimes those streams stop working and need to be relaunched. I'm right now running process via bash for each python file to ensure nothing crashes, but I'd rather have a single "server" if you will managing the whole process.

The goal is to eventually have a dashboard of sorts showing the status of each named subprocess, and some stats. I'd like to be able, via dashboard, to relaunch or just stop any of the processes without killing the server, but being able to relaunch those processed at any time.

Is this possible? Any direction?

Most python websockets examples are server/client. I'm just looking for an indefinite client with a relaunch on error w/o ever killing off the server.

Answer (score 1):

I think, [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) is what you are looking for.
It has no web dashboard "out of the box", but it has some [plugins](http://supervisord.org/plugins.html) that implement such feature though.